# pkgobj\Debug\Package_Manifest.xml is read-only?

Tags: visual-studio

When I package a Sharepoint 2010 project in Visual Studio 2010, I occasionally get the following error message:

```
Access to the path 'C:\path-to-my-project\pkgobj\Debug\Package_Manifest.xml' is denied.
```

I checked the file, and it seems to be read-only. Clearing the read-only flag helps, but eventually the problem reoccurs. What's causing it and how can I fix it for good?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to get around the problem by checking-out the AppManifest.xml file in the project, thereby removing the read-only.  For some reason the publish process copies this file over and keeps the read-only flag, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the visual studio as Administrator

Comment: It made no difference. I don't see what administrator privileges have to do with the file system read-only flag.

Answer (score 0):

The UAC requires that you run Visual Studio as a system administrator.

To develop SharePoint solutions, you must have sufficient permissions to run and debug SharePoint solutions. Before you can test a SharePoint solution, take the following steps to ensure that you have the necessary permissions:

- Add your user account as an Administrator on the system.
- Add your user account as a Farm Administrator for the SharePoint server.
- In SharePoint Central Administration, click the Manage the farm administrators group link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231582(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Did you even read the question? This is not a Sharepoint permissions issue, it's an issue with Visual Studio. You don't even _need_ to have a functioning Sharepoint instance to create a .wsp package in Visual Studio. That said, I am running Visual Studio with elevated privileges, and my user account is both a local administrator as well as the Sharepoint farm administrator.

Comment: I did read your question and I've experienced the problem myself. However, I delevop on a server with SharePoint. Regardless, VS need the rights.

Another scenario where this might happen is if use a version controler and you your file is versioned and marked as read-only by default. Content of the folders bin, debug, release should not be versioned as they are automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue too. I don't know what was the problem exactly, but once I have logged off and log in again, this problem was gone. Probably it was because I changed password recently....